# can't do mapping in flutter

Tags: flutter, listview, mapping

I can't do the mapping

I have declared "ItemList" above. tp why can not be called and error .

Please help me!! i'm just learning to vibrate, i've tried renaming var but it still won't get called

````
  HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
 var Itemlist = [
    Items(
        id: 1,
        nama: 'Baso Aci',
        harga: 5000,
        jumlah: 2,
        deskripsi: 'xxxx'),
  ];
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Keranjang Belanja'),
          backgroundColor: Colors.greenAccent[400],
        ),
        bottomNavigationBar: Container(
            height: 50,
            color: Colors.greenAccent[400],
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
              children: [
                Text('Total',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontFamily: 'serif',
                        fontSize: 20,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                Text('Rp. ',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontFamily: 'serif',
                        fontSize: 20,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
              ],
            )),
        body: ListView(
          children: Itemlist
          .map(item) => CardItem(Items(id: item.id, nama: item.nama, harga: item.harga, jumlah: item.jumlah, deskripsi: item.deskripsi)))
    )
  }
} ```
````

Comment: You need to call ```toList()``` method on the ```map```. ```itemlist.map((item)=>CardItem()).toList()```

Comment: @EhsanAskari I've tried, still can't?

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: still the same as the first problem, "Undefined name 'Itemlist'.

Comment: oh, You need to declare the variable inside ```_HomePageState```

Comment: Hey, You have declared the variable inside another class. That's why you can not access it. You need to declare it in ```_HomePageState```

Comment: Thank you!! I just realized, I wrote the list in the wrong another class

Answer (score 0):

Please try like this

Item list declaration inside _HomePageState as mention by
Ehsan Askari

```
List<Items>itemList=[Items(id: "id")];
```

Use map as below

```
ListView(
        children: itemList.map((item) => CardItem(items:item)).toList())
```

Your CardItem widget

```
class CardItem extends StatelessWidget {
  final Items items;
  const CardItem({Key? key,required this.items}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

Comment: CardItem should be widget as ListView accepts only List<Widget>

Comment: Thank you for answering!! I just realized, it turns out I wrote the wrong list in another class